# Are there non-DC KDCs in Active Directory?

Tags: windows, active-directory, kerberos

Each Active Directory domain controller acts as a KDC, AFAIK. But are there any cases when Active Directory could have a **standalone** KDC server? Is it even possible with Active Directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. It's not separate service that you can install. It's embedded.

Comment: ...and has been since the first version of Active Directory.